# what happened to the subsonic screencasts?

Tags: subsonic

None of them are available in the docs. I see embedded iframes pointing to "silverlight.services.live.com", but no video. FF shows blank, IE7 shows HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Please contact the webmaster of the site for such questions. And at least include the URL where you are missing content.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all screencasts are unavailable. Ex: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Repo_5_Minute_Demo

Comment: Subsonic website says stackoverflow is the official support forum for all things subsonic. http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight live streaming - the MS service launched to support things like this - went offline and I need to move *every single one* of the screencasts I've made for SubSonic over the last 3 years.

This is going to take some time - I'll get there but it will be a few weeks.